# Load imageView from Xcassets using Switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, switch-statement

I have the images for @1 @2 and @3 in the Xcassets and am trying to load the image onto a scrollview page using the code below that switches the image due to the age its on. The page is determined by the position and the switch statement is called in the viewWillLoad function. The images are not loading but sounds are working so I know the it is the image loading that is the problem. Can you help?

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.imageView.image = nil
}



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    showImageView()

    let tapGestureImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTapGestureImage:"))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureImage)
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}




// MARK: BWWalkthroughPage Implementation

func walkthroughDidScroll(position: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {

    // getting the page number from the scroll position. First page loads as nil so want it to be zero.

    screenPage  = Int(((position / view.bounds.size.width) + 1) - 1)
}



func showImageView() {

    // change imageView in bundle depending on which scrollview page you are.
    switch screenPage {

    case 0:

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Aligator", inBundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    case 1:

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Bear", inBundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    default:
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are important for you to understand.
You do not need to add/remove the image view from the view hierarchy over and over. Simply calling `imageView.image = nil` will suffice.

The second thing is that you don't need to use the full method `UIImage(named:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:)`. You should be able to simply use `UIImage(named:)`. If you find yourself having to use the former, you may be taking bigger bites than you can handle at this stage in your career.

The third thing is that when you override a method, you must call super in 99% of the cases.

Here's an example that should work:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override fun viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTapGestureImage:"))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated: animated)
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        showImageView()
    }

    func walkthroughDidScroll(position: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {
        screenPage  = Int(((position / view.bounds.size.width) + 1) - 1)
    }

    func showImageView() {
        switch screenPage {
        case 0:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Aligator")
        case 1:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Bear")
        default:
            imageView.image = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have done that but the imageView stays as Aligator in all views.

Comment: Then there is clearly something wrong with your outlet connections. Are you using IBOutlet connections at all? Make sure that our xib or storyboard is good.

Comment: I have checked it and the connections are good. If they werent the sounds wouldnt work that are triggered in the same manner. As a side note all the 26 imageViews are connected to the single imageView in this Class. Only one doesnt fire but is connected and I have to look into it tonight.

Comment: The code to change the image is correct. The issue is with the screenPage that is not giving the correct value due to being nil and with a value after first screen.